# Eclipse strange exception on debug

Tags: java, eclipse

If I try run as Java application my code runs ok. But when I use debug as Java application exception file not found is thrown. Here  is my code:

```
public class SecureGameServer {

    public static final ApplicationContext ac= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("lion-server.xml");//Here I got the exception
    //public static final ApplicationContext ac= new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src\\main\\resources\\lion-server.xml");This code doesnt work too
    public static DefaultChannelGroup gameChannels;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       ...
}
}
```

Whats wrong? The program is working well. But I cant debug it.

Comment: Do you have any arguments or environment variables set up with your run configuration that aren't in the debug configuration? Can you post a complete example that can be compiled and run? What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I use Juno. The project is very big (about  50 files).

Comment: Man, I wish my projects were that big.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to just a single file? That may find the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the name `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` would indicate the application context file `lion-server.xml` must be located somewhere on your classpath. Ensure that this is the case and that the file has well formed XML.

As you have included the Eclipse tag, the file can be located in your resource folder, e.g. `src\main\resources`.

Comment: lion-server.xml is already in src\main\resources. When I use run as Java Application everything is fine.

Comment: I would do a refresh on the project. Eclipse's view of the project may be out of sync.

Comment: @bossman Hit "F5" in the project view, or right-click and "Refresh", at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I have found the exception was on URLClasspath. I dont know why but there was breakpoint. I have just resumed it by pressing F8. Thanks to all.